# Neural Network for training set depending on each other

Tags: neural-network

is it possible to create a feed forward neural network where the training set
depends on each other. Say, for example, I want to train a network to predict
the raiting for products. I would split a product into features x1, x2, x3, ...
and create a neural network where each input neuron represents one feature and the output neuron represents the rating for the product.

But what if I have an additional constraint: a user has only say 100 rating points per month, 
so the sum of the rating of one user never exeeds 100. Now the network should predict 
for one user how he would distribute his 100 rating points on a given list of products. Is this possible with a feed forward network?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question !

Personally I would try to look at it that way:

**Training:**

First train the network the way you would normally. The training set you use must satisfy the constraint !

**Prediction:**

1. Predict the ratings using the feed forward net you trained regardless of the constraint (it should ideally not be far from 100 since the training set you used satisfies the constraint)
2. Then treat your problem as an optimization problem where you want to satisfy the 100 points constraint by changing as few ratings as possible and each one as little as possible (you can have an optimization criteria which minimizes the deltas for instance)